# Nextjs 13 (with App Directory) Warning: Prop `className` did not match

Tags: next.js, material-ui, styled-components

I am using the latest version of Nextjs 13 with app directory. I am currently using "styled-components" library with "Material UI".

I am constantly getting this error even though I have taken the recommended steps to prevent it.

Here's how my next.config.js looks like:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And this is the Layout.ts file:

```
"use client";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar/Navbar";
import ClientOnly from "../components/ClientOnly";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import theme from "../theme";
import "../globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import StyledComponentsRegistry from "../components/StyledComponentsRegistry";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <StyledComponentsRegistry>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
        </StyledComponentsRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
```

Here is the content for StyledComponentsRegistery:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";
import { ServerStyleSheet, StyleSheetManager } from "styled-components";

export default function StyledComponentsRegistry({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  // Only create stylesheet once with lazy initial state
  // x-ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state
  const [styledComponentsStyleSheet] = useState(() => new ServerStyleSheet());

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const styles = styledComponentsStyleSheet.getStyleElement();
    styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance.clearTag();
    return <>{styles}</>;
  });

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") return <>{children}</>;

  return (
    <StyleSheetManager sheet={styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance}>
      {children}
    </StyleSheetManager>
  );
}
```

I am importing styled from @mui/material in my styles.ts files like so:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material";

export const PromoStyled = styled("div")`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  .tagline {
    max-width: 600px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 900;
    opacity: 90%;
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.palette.primary.main};
    text-shadow: #e0ffce -1px 0px, #e0ffce 0px 3px, #e0ffce 3px 0px,
      #e0ffce 0px -1px, #e0ffce 5px 7px 0px;
  }

  .teaser-image {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
`;
```

I have tried everything but the error does not go away. Also, the styling does not apply correctly. When the components get rendered, there's a glitch that renders default styling and then the new styes load. It's very confusing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try changing your Layout files extension to `.tsx` instead of `.ts`